# How does the voicing for "Ma vie de Courgette" work in British and American English?

Tags: translation, voice-acting, my-life-as-a-courgette

[Ma vie de Courgette](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2321405/) is a Swiss/French animation that was nominated for an Oscar this year. In the UK it's titled "My Life as a Courgette", while in America it's called "My Life as a Zucchini" (as that's what Americans call the vegetable).

But when I look at the cast list I only see the original French cast and the American cast (Nick Offerman, Ellen Page, etc). How does this work with respect to the voicing and script for the UK version? The main character is nicknamed Courgette/Zucchini so it must be in the script.

Did the American actors record two versions, one with "Courgette" and one with "Zucchini"? Or is there a separate British cast that's not listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this on DVD a while back and I can confirm that the American cast did record multiple versions. In my British English version the boy is called "Courgette" and there is no separate cast, the same American actors provide the voices.

There are also separate trailers for the [British English 'Courgette'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2GO9MiioCk) and [American English 'Zucchini'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bd2TOf1kmfk) versions (not available when I asked the question) which show the alternate dialogue.